# Could not download flutter_embedding_debug.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

I have a problem when I run the sample flutter project in android studio.
(I use manjaro)

I see this error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paPpI.png)

I did see [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46878) and Blasten's solution, but I don't know what should I do after downloading the file?

Also, I did see [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23553) and Shaileshpanthee's solution and try it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: i am having same issue with new flutter sdk, this happens after i update my flutter version, did you get the solution for it

Comment: What dependencies have you got in pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I tried this and work for me.

```
flutter channel beta
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```